# CCC Settings aren't saving

Tags: ati, 64-bit

I'm new to Linux and I just installed AMD drivers using the guide at the Unofficial AMD Wiki:

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. I installed Catalyst version 12.6, 64-bit. Basically, some settings aren't saving and I don't know if I can fix it with my current setup, or if I need to uninstall the drivers and downgrade to an earlier version. Thanks for reading!

---

Description of problem:

Steps to reproduce:

1. Make changes to any of the default settings in the Display Manager -> DTV ->
   Adjustments tab.
2. Click apply, OK.
3. Relog/reboot/close and reopen CCC.

Actual result: Settings return to default. The position of the overscan slider
remains the same in the GUI, but the functionality of the setting returns to
default.

Expected result: Settings should be saved after relog/reboot.

I have to manually go into CCC every time I relog/reboot to adjust the overscan
slider so I don't have a big black border around my screen.

Answer (score 3):

I removed Catalyst version 12.6 and installed Catalyst version 12.4 using the wiki linked above. Things seems to be working now. The settings are being saved.